# ffmpeg reads wrong timecode

Tags: ffmpeg, video, encoding

I use ffmpeg to generate proxy files but for some reason the timecode is wrong. When i open the original file in DaVinci Resolve it always shows double the timecode that ffmpeg (ffprobe) reads. e.g. original video in Resolve shows Start TC 00:00:24:00 and ffprobe shows 00:00:12:00. When I convert the original video to ProRes it changes the timecode to the wrong one.

**EDIT**: timecode from Resolve is the right one from camera

Is there a way to fix this behavior?

Original video:

```
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'DSCF6599.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2021-11-01T11:46:42.000000Z
    original_format : Digital Camera
    original_format-eng: Digital Camera
    comment         : FUJIFILM DIGITAL CAMERA X-T3
    comment-eng     : FUJIFILM DIGITAL CAMERA X-T3
  Duration: 00:00:07.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 207092 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: hevc (Main 10) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p10le(pc, bt2020nc/bt2020/arib-std-b67), 4096x2160, 198547 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 50k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-11-01T11:46:42.000000Z
      timecode        : 00:00:12:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s24le (lpcm / 0x6D63706C), 48000 Hz, 2 channels, s32 (24 bit), 2304 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-11-01T11:46:42.000000Z
      timecode        : 00:00:12:00
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 1 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-11-01T11:46:42.000000Z
      timecode        : 00:00:12:00
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

Converted video:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'DSCF6599.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: qt  
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    comment         : FUJIFILM DIGITAL CAMERA X-T3
    comment-eng     : FUJIFILM DIGITAL CAMERA X-T3
  Duration: 00:00:07.00, start: 12.000000, bitrate: 14238 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: prores (Proxy) (apco / 0x6F637061), yuv422p10le(tv, bt2020nc/bt2020/reserved, progressive), 2048x1080, 12694 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 50k tbn, 50k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 prores
      timecode        : 00:00:12:00
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : TimeCodeHandler
      timecode        : 00:00:12:00
```

Used this command to convert:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel cuda -i DSCF6599.MOV -acodec pcm_s16le -vcodec prores -profile:v 0 -vf scale=-1:1080 ./Proxy/DSCF6599.MOV
```

Comment: How do you know the problem isn't with DaVinci Resolve? First step when encountering problems in ffmpeg is to always try the most recent ffmpeg. Preferably a build from the git master branch. See the [download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page for links to already compiled ffmpeg.

Comment: It's not Resolve problem because the time code it shows is the same timecode that is shown in camera (should've mention this in original post). I've just tried building ffmpeg from source and it still gives me wrong timecode.

Comment: @llogan Just also tried to copy everything to new file and the result is the same.

`ffmpeg -i ~/Videos/Test/DSCF6599.MOV -map 0 -map_metadata 0 -movflags use_metadata_tags -c copy -copy_unknown ~/Videos/Test/Proxy/test.MOV`

Comment: Perhaps a bug, but I did not try it myself. Search the [bug tracker](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/), and consider submitting a report if you think it is a bug and if you don't find any duplicate tickets.